# XML XElement building an xml document

Tags: c#, xml

Hi I am new to XML building, I basically didn't use it before, I always preferred json.

I have a solution where I just make it with string and convert to XML object, but how can I do it with XElement class?

This is the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <requestblock version="3.67">
    <alias>ALIAS</alias>
    <request type="AUTH"> 
       <operation> 
          <sitereference>test12345</sitereference> 
          <accounttypedescription>TEST</accounttypedescription> 
          <parenttransactionreference>12-3-4567</parenttransactionreference> 
       </operation> 
       <merchant> 
          <orderreference>Example recurring auth</orderreference>
       </merchant> 
       <customer> </customer> 
       <billing> 
          <amount currencycode="GBP">1234</amount> 
          <subscription type="TEST">
             <number>1</number>
          </subscription> 
       </billing> 
       <settlement/>
    </request> 
 </requestblock>
```

I already have a part of the code like this:

```
       XElement address =
            new XElement("alias", "TEST",
            new XElement("request", new XAttribute("type", "AUTH"),
            new XElement("City", "Mercer Island"),
            new XElement("State", "WA"),
            new XElement("Postal", "68042")
       ));
```

But I have a problem with alias, because alias is closed after all elements, not in the same notation:

```
<alias>TEST
    <request type="AUTH">
        <City>Mercer Island</City>
        <State>WA</State>
        <Postal>68042</Postal>
    </request>
</alias>
```

As you can see  notation is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting alias as your root element, which should be requestblock. If you start with requestblock like this:

```
XElement address =
       new XElement("requestblock", new XAttribute("version",3.67),
       new XElement("alias", "TEST"),
       new XElement("request", new XAttribute("type", "AUTH"),
       new XElement("City", "Mercer Island"),
       new XElement("State", "WA"),
       new XElement("Postal", "68042")
```

It'l give you

```
<requestblock version="3.67">
   <alias>TEST</alias>
   <request type="AUTH">
      <City>Mercer Island</City>
      <State>WA</State>
      <Postal>68042</Postal>
   </request>
</requestblock>
```